# How to use static library in c++ UWP application?

Tags: c++, uwp, static-libraries

How to create a c++ static library for UWP app?
How to link the above library to UWP app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to create a c++ static library for UWP app?

**To Create a static library** 
**1.)** Open Visual studio 2017 -> New -> Project... ->
 Visual C++ -> Windows Universal -> Static Library (Universal Windows)
Your project need to contain two files. 1. yourLibrary.h, 2. yourLibrary.cpp
(**I'm not sure if Static Library that is not UWP static library will work with UWP**)
**Example code for yourLibrary.h**

```
#pragma once
int minus(int a, int b);
int mul(int a, int b);
```

**Example code for yourLibrary.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "yourLibrary.h"
int minus(int a, int b){return a-b}
int mul(int a, int b){return a*b}
```

**2.)** On Solution Explorer on the left. Right click your projrct name-> Properties->vC/C++-> General-> Consume Windows Runtime Extension-> Yes(/ZW)(**Why?**)

**3.)** Build -> Build Solution

 Your Static library is now located at your solution folder(folder that contain .sln)-> Debug-> yourSolutionName
You should have .lib .pdb .pri in this folder(.lib is your static library and **I don't know what .pdb .pri is supposed to be**)

> How to link the above library to UWP app?

**1.)** Copy .h and .lib from your library project and place them some where under your project folder. e.g. TestApp(contain .sln)/TestApp(Contain .vcxproj)/Mylibrary
**2.)** In Visual Studio, Right click your project name -> Add -> Existing Item... -> add .lib and .h
**3.)** On **pch.h**, add this line `#include "..\MyLibrary\yourLibrary.h"`(**I'm not sure if you can do this somewhere else**)

And now you can use function minus() and mul() in your app.

I'm just geting into c++ and this is how I make it to work and I might did some unnecessary procedure above. So please correct me.